# Handling permalink user update when permalink is already taken Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, permalinks

I wanted some advice about how to handle `to_param` in regards to `permalinks`

Basically this is what happens.

- Create a new company
- The company `:name` is then parameterized and saved as a `:permalink` in the db
- Updating an existing company enables you to change the `:permalink`
- There are validations to ensure user updated `:permalink` is unique

The problem I'm having is occurring when updating the company's `:permalink` to something that already exists. The uniqueness validation works which is great, but it changes the `params[:id]` to the invalid permalink instead of reseting and using the existing `params[:id]`

When I try to edit the `permalink` to something else I get a flash validation error of `"Name already taken"` because it thinks I'm editing the company of the already existing `:permalink` (company). The URL reflects the change in `permalink` since my `companies_controller.rb` is using `@company = Company.find_by_permalink[:id])`

I wanted to know the best way to handle this issue?

```
class Companies < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_permalink
  before_update :update_permalink

  attr_accessible :name, :permalink

  validates :name, :permalink, uniqueness: { message: 'already taken' }

  def to_param
    permalink
  end

  private

  def set_permalink_url
    self.permalink = name.parameterize
  end

  def update_permalink_url
    self.permalink = permalink.parameterize
  end


end
```

Apologies if I'm not making too much sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to handle this with an `after_rollback` callback.

```
 after_rollback :restore_permalink

 def restore_permalink
   self.permalink = permalink_was if permalink_changed?
 end
```

here's how it works : every update / destroy in Rails is wrapped in a transaction. If the save fails, the transaction rollbacks and triggers the callback.
The callback then restores the old value (`permalink_was`) if it was changed since the record has been loaded.

See [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) and [ActiveRecord::Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_rollback) for more info.

**EDIT**

On the other hand, there *may* be another solution (untested) - just define your accessor like this :

```
 def permalink=( value )
   permalink_will_change! unless @permalink == value
   @permalink = value
 end
```

This way, the permalink will not be marked as dirty if the new value is identical to the old one, and so AR will not try to update the column.

**Explanation:**

i don't know on which version of rails it was implemented (it is relatively recent), but here's how "dirtyness" works :

- your "standard" (automagically generated) attribute setters basicly call
  `#{your_attribute}_will_change!` before setting the associated
  instance variable (even if you set the exact same value than before)
- when you call `save`, ActiveRecords looks for attributes that have changed ("dirty") and builds the SQL UPDATE query using ONLY these attributes (for performance reasons, mostly)
- so if you want to avoid your permalink to appear in the query when it is unchanged, i think you have to override the standard setter - or avoid mass-assignment and only set `permalink` if it has changed

Comment: Hi m_x, thank you for taking the time and explaining various concepts. It's much appreciated, thank you. I'm just having problems with the after_rollback callback as it's still changing the url (permalink) instead of reverting back to the permalink_was. So, instead of using the existing id it's changing the id to a different company (eg. the already existing profile_url that the user tried to changing to).

Comment: hmmm... my bad. i think the second solution i gave you should work better (remove the callback)

Comment: Thanks again M_x. Is it possible to get more insight how the second solution works. I'm entirely sure how to implement it. Appreciate your help.